# How to add <li> elements to a <ul> class with selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

Example:

```
<ul class="testNumbers"> 
     <li ng-if="vm.numbers.length> 0" ng-repeat="number in vm.numbers track by $ index" class= "ng-binding ng-scope" style = "">01</li>"
```

I would like to add several `<li>` dynamically with numbers 02, 03, 04 ...

Comment: I am curious as to your final requirements. Why do you think you need to do this with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to install Selenium for .Net

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
            var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///C:/Users/jezequiel/Desktop/c.html");

            var script = @"var node = document.createElement('LI');
                        node.setAttribute('ng-if', 'blah blah blah');
                        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arguments[1]));
                        arguments[0].appendChild(node); 
                        ";

            var e = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul"));
            string[] items = { "02", "03", "04" };

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                js.ExecuteScript(script, e, item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Justin, thanks for your help.
It worked in part, only with <li> but I need it complete =
<li ng-if = "vm.numbers.length> 0" ng-repeat = "number in vm.numbers track by $ index" class = "ng-binding ng-scope" style = ""

Comment: You're supposed to do some of the work yourself. I've edited my answer to include a call to [setAttrribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)